# Bash script that will validate a user's membership in a specified group

Tags: linux, bash

```
Please enter a username: student
Now enter your membership: root
Membership is valid!

ubuntu@user:~$ ./membership.sh
Please enter a username: doesnotexist
Now enter your membership: alsodoesnotexist
Both are not found - why are you even asking me this?

ubuntu@user:~$ ./membership.sh
Please enter a username: student
Now enter your membership: doesnotexist
One exists, one does not. You figure out which.

ubuntu@user:~$ ./membership.sh
Please enter a username: student
Now enter your membership: sudo
Membership invalid but available to join.
```

I need to convert the conversation above to a bash script. This is what I come up with:

```
banner="Welcome to the sexy hackers Club"
now="$(date)"
computer_name="$(hostname)"

echo "Date: $now"
echo "$banner: $computer_name"
echo  " "

read -p "Please enter a user name: " USER
read -p "Now enter a group: " MEMBERSHIP


if [[ $USER == 'student' && $MEMBERSHIP == 'root' ]];
then 
echo "Membership valid!"
else
echo "Both are not found"
if  [[ $USER == 'student' ||  $MEMBERSHIP == 'root' ]];
then
echo "One exist, one does not"
if [[ $USER == 'student' || $MEMBERSHIP == 'sudo' ]];
then
echo "Membership invalid but available to join."
fi
fi
fi
```

The first, and second steps work perfectly but the problem is with the 3rd and 4th
conversations. if I add user `student` and a wrong membership it should say `One exists, one does not` and in the 4th conversation if I add `student` but sudo as membership, it should say `Membership invalid but available to join.`

The problem with my scrip is that the last two conversation gets mixed, I can't find a way to make them unique. I need to create a short Bash script that will validate a user's membership in a specified group. This script should not take any arguments and, instead, should prompt the user to enter a `username` and a `membership`. This script should first check to see if the `username` and `membership` are found on our system to get **Membership valid!**. If **BOTH ARE NOT FOUND**, the script should respond ***Both are not found*** but **If ONLY ONE IS FOUND**, it should respond **One exists, one does not**. **If BOTH ARE FOUND**, it should also check to see if the user is a member and If the **USER IS A MEMBER OF THE GROUP**, the script should respond `Membership valid!` otherwise, it should respond `Membership invalid but available to join`. To be clear, the script should initially prompt twice for `user input` (the prompt does not matter) and then only respond once with one of the four specified responses.

Comment: First indent your code.  You will see the order and context of each `if then else fi` block.  Right now it is hard to figure out where it starts and ends.

Comment: the problem is that if I knew what I was doing or what I was supposed to do, I wouldn't be here posting this question and code. @Nic3500

Comment: The problem is the attitude.  Code indentation will help you see the `if then else fi` blocks.  It will then be easier to see the logic traps that you coded, and make it easier for us to help.

Comment: It's more than "if the `username` and `membership` are found on our system". It's if `username` is found and is a member of the `membership` group. Otherwise you are just checking if `user` exists and if `group` exists and not requiring any connection between them. Further, `user` will never be a member of `root` group. They may be members of `wheel` or `sudo` groups which can execute some/all commands as super-user, but they will not be members of group `root`. Just use `grep $username /etc/group` and then parse with `awk` to get group membership for `username`

Comment: UPPERCASE variable names are generally reserved for environment variables or shell internal variables -- use lowercase.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Hi David, you are right in everything you said. The only problem with this script and what you are saying is that it shouldn't really check `users` and 'groups' in a real Unix system, is more to check if I was able to replicate the conversation above but in a bash script. which is why they asked me for input and explicitly said to use a fake `username` that does exist in the system in any system.

Comment: then, I was supposed to run`$ ./script-tester.sh /path-to/myscript.sh` using this second script to check if the script I made was made correctly. Since the second script was made using `root` I didn't have any way to `cat`or open the file to see how the checking on my `script` works, something pretty cool um?

Comment: You don't need to `cat`, just pipe the output of the first script to the second, e.g. `./script1.sh | ./script2.sh` so `script2` can read the output from `script1` on its `stdin`. Or, with bash, you can use *Process Substitution* to feed a `while` loop with the output from `script1`, e.g. `while read -r line; do ... done < <(./script1)` -- the space between `< <` is mandatory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

read -p "Please enter a username: " user
read -p "Now enter a MEMBERSHIP: " MEMBERSHIP

u=$(id ${user} 2>/dev/null | awk '{print $3}' 2>/dev/null)
g=$(getent MEMBERSHIP ${MEMBERSHIP} 2>/dev/null)
m=$(echo $u 2>/dev/null | grep -w ${MEMBERSHIP} 2>/dev/null)

if [[ ! -n $u ]] && [[ ! -n $g ]] ; then echo "Both are not found"
elif ( [[ -n $u ]] && [[ -n $g ]] ) && [[ ! -n $m ]] ; then echo "Membership invalid but available to join."
elif [[ -n $m ]] ; then echo "Membership valid!"
elif ( [[ ! -n $u ]] && [[ -n $g ]] ) || ( [[ -n $u ]] && [[ ! -n $g ]] ) ; then echo "One exist, one does not."
fi
```

This is the correct answer to the script. Four different answers to four different actions within the script.

Answer (score 2):

Whitespace would make your code a lot easier to understand. This is what you have with indentation added:

```
if [[ $USER == 'student' && $MEMBERSHIP == 'root' ]];
then 
  echo "Membership valid!"
else
  echo "Both are not found"
  if  [[ $USER == 'student' ||  $MEMBERSHIP == 'root' ]];
  then
    echo "One exist, one does not"
    if [[ $USER == 'student' || $MEMBERSHIP == 'sudo' ]];
    then
      echo "Membership invalid but available to join."
    fi
  fi
fi
```

The output mixes because in the `else` case you always print "Both are not found" but then you could additionally print the other statements as well because they're all part of the same conditional branch.

Instead of `else`, you should be using `elif`.

```
if [[ $USER == 'student' && $MEMBERSHIP == 'root' ]]
then 
  echo "Membership valid!"
elif [[ $USER == 'student' ||  $MEMBERSHIP == 'root' ]]
then
  echo "One exist, one does not"
elif <more conditions...>
  <more logic>
fi #end the entire statement with one fi
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but is not working, this code won't display the **Both are not found** error even after I added  `elif [[ $USER == 'student' && $MEMBERSHIP == 'root' ]];
  then
  echo "Not found"` I should get any of these 4 responses depending on what I do. **valid**, **no found**, **only one exists**, and **membership invalid but available to join**

Answer (score 2):

Continuing from my comment, you can't just check that the user and group exists on the system and conclude the membership is valid, you have to validate the user is a member of the entered group. There are several ways to do this, but the easiest is just to validate the user and group exist on the system by checking the return of `getent` called on `passwd` and `group` databases.

The to determine membership, just `grep $user /etc/group` to generate a list of the groups the member belongs to, and parse the output with `awk` to verify that one of the groups returned matches the membership (group) entered.

Don't use UPPERCASE variables names, those are generally reserved for environment variables or internal shell variables. Lowercase variable names are fine.

Putting it altogether, you could do something similar to the following:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

## input user and group
read -p "Please enter a user name: " user
read -p "Now enter a group: " group

## validate user exists on system
getent passwd "$user" >/dev/null
[ $? -ne 0 ] && { 
  printf "%s is not a valid user on the system.\n" "$user" >&2
  exit 1
}

## validate group found on system
getent group "$group" >/dev/null
[ $? -ne 0 ] && { 
  printf "%s is not a valid group on the system.\n" "$group" >&2
  exit 1
}

## validate user is member of group
grep "$user" /etc/group |                   # get groups user is a member of
awk -F":" -v g="$group" '                   # set field sep and g (group)
  $1 == g {                                 # group in list of groups
    found = 1                               # set found flag
    print "Menbership Valid!"               # output success
    exit
  }
  END { 
    if (!found)                             # if group not found
      print "User not Member of group " g   # output result
  }
'
```

**Example Use/Output**

Check if I am a member of the `wheel` group (I am):

```
$ bash verifymember.sh
Please enter a user name: david
Now enter a group: wheel
Menbership Valid!
```

Check if `foo` is a member of `wheel` (there is no user `foo` on system):

```
$ bash verifymember.sh
Please enter a user name: foo
Now enter a group: wheel
foo is not a valid user on the system.
```

Check if I am a member of the `foo` group (there is no `foo` group on the system):

```
$ bash verifymember.sh
Please enter a user name: david
Now enter a group: foo
foo is not a valid group on the system.
```

Check if I'm a member of the `audio` group (I'm not, but it is a valid group):

```
$ bash verifymember.sh
Please enter a user name: david
Now enter a group: audio
User not Member of group audio
```

That covers all four possible cases (1) valid member; (2) user doesn't exist; (3) group doesn't exist; and (4) user is not a member of valid group.

Comment: I'm Upvoting this work because even if this is a whole different code for a whole different situation, this is something I want in my notes, something that can become very handy in the future, thank you very much, David.